# Does Windows log its tasks and events?

Tags: windows-7, event-log

There is a computer in my network at work of which the settings somehow have changed. Either someone changed something or it changed by itself. Is there any log or event manager to have a look at what happend? The computer is running Win 7 enterprise edition.

Comment: Go to Start < Run and type in "eventvwr". From there, you can access the log files. I'm just not sure you will find what you are looking for. System restore might be more usefull. It will return your computer settings to a previous state.

Comment: Also have a look at this post: http://superuser.com/questions/610223/is-it-possible-to-log-file-system-events-in-windows-or-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Windows logs by opening the [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7).

To access it do the following:

Start > Run > Enter `eventvwr` > hit return. This is valid for all versions of Windows from XP.